# [magento2]I've added the custom attribute to customer_address_entity and display in UI form

Tags: magento2

[magento2]I've added the custom attribute to customer_address_entity and display in UI form. how to save the custom attribute to database when submit form
[image]

Comment: What code did you use to create and display the custom attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in your `Setup/UpgradeData.php` if you don't have this file then create one.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Setup;


use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                'custom_attribute',
                [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'Customer Product Points',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'system' => 0,
                ]
            );
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'custom_attribute');
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer']);
        $attribute->save();
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Try this code and value will be saved automatically.